# android debugging ddms vs eclipse debugger / code not working on android 4.0

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-emulator, ddms

been trying to figure out why my code wont run in the new 4.0 emulator for a few days now and cant seem to get to the bottom of it, My code which runs just fine in the 2.2 sdk wont work at all in the 4.0 sdk emulator, as a result of this Ive been trying to track down some tutorials on debugging but cant quite seem to get a clear explanation as to which one is best or quite frankly a clear way as to how to execute the functions, so my question is which is best and what is the best way to do it?

Update:

Exceptions:

```
11-23 10:16:34.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): java.lang.RuntimeException:
        Unable to resume activity {com.testapp2.second/com.testapp2.second.activities.AuthorizationActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-23 10:16:34.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2443)
```

here is my code:
activity1:

```
package com.testapp2.second.activities;

import com.testapp2.second.OTweetApplication;
import com.testapp2.second.R;

import twitter4j.ResponseList;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class Testapp2Activity extends ListActivity {

private Twitter twitter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
app = (OTweetApplication)getApplication();
twitter = app.getTwitter();

setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
if (!app.isAuthorized()) {
  beginAuthorization();
} else {
  loadTimelineIfNotLoaded();
}
}

private void loadTimelineIfNotLoaded() {
loadHomeTimeline();
}

private void beginAuthorization() {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AuthorizationActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}

private void loadHomeTimeline() {
try {
  ResponseList<Status> statii = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
  StatusListAdapter adapter = new StatusListAdapter(this, statii);
  setListAdapter(adapter);
} catch (TwitterException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}

private class StatusListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Status> {

public StatusListAdapter(Context context, ResponseList<Status> statii) {
  super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, statii);
}

}
}
```

activity 2:

```
package com.testapp2.second.activities;

import com.testapp2.second.OTweetApplication;
import com.testapp2.second.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class AuthorizationActivity extends Activity {

private OTweetApplication app;
private WebView webView;

private WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
  // the URL we're looking for looks like this:
  // http://otweet.com/authenticated?oauth_token=1234567890qwertyuiop
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
  if (uri.getHost().equals("otweet.com")) {
    String token = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
    if (null != token) {
      webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      app.authorized();
      finish();
    } else {
      // tell user to try again 
    }
  } else {
    super.onLoadResource(view, url);
  }
 }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
app = (OTweetApplication)getApplication();
setContentView(R.layout.authorization_view);
setUpViews();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
String authURL = app.beginAuthorization();
webView.loadUrl(authURL);
}

private void setUpViews() {
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
}

}
```

extended application:

```
package com.testapp2.second;

import com.testapp2.second.authorization.OAuthHelper;

import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import android.app.Application;

public class OTweetApplication extends Application {

private Twitter twitter;
private RequestToken currentRequestToken;
private OAuthHelper oAuthHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
oAuthHelper = new OAuthHelper(this);
twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
oAuthHelper.configureOAuth(twitter);
}

public Twitter getTwitter() {
return twitter;
}

public boolean isAuthorized() {
return oAuthHelper.hasAccessToken();
}

public String beginAuthorization() {
try {
  if (null == currentRequestToken) {
    currentRequestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
  }
  return currentRequestToken.getAuthorizationURL();
} catch (TwitterException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}

public boolean authorize(String pin) {
try {
  AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(currentRequestToken, pin);
  oAuthHelper.storeAccessToken(accessToken);
  return true;
} catch (TwitterException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Unable to authorize user", e); 
}
}

public void authorized() {
try {
  AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
  oAuthHelper.storeAccessToken(accessToken);
} catch (TwitterException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Unable to authorize user", e); 
}

}

}
```

oauth helper:

```
package com.testapp2.second.authorization;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.testapp2.second.R;

import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

public class OAuthHelper {

private static final String APPLICATION_PREFERENCES = "app_prefs";
private static final String AUTH_KEY = "auth_key";
private static final String AUTH_SEKRET_KEY = "auth_secret_key";
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private AccessToken accessToken;
private String consumerSecretKey;
private String consumerKey;
private Context context;

public OAuthHelper(Context context) {
this.context = context;
prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APPLICATION_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
loadConsumerKeys();
accessToken = loadAccessToken();
}

public void configureOAuth(Twitter twitter) {
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecretKey);
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
}

public boolean hasAccessToken() {
return null != accessToken;
}

public void storeAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken) {
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString(AUTH_KEY, accessToken.getToken());
editor.putString(AUTH_SEKRET_KEY, accessToken.getTokenSecret());
editor.commit();
this.accessToken = accessToken;
}

private AccessToken loadAccessToken() {
String token = prefs.getString(AUTH_KEY, null);
String tokenSecret = prefs.getString(AUTH_SEKRET_KEY, null);
if (null != token && null != tokenSecret) {
  return new AccessToken(token, tokenSecret);
} else {
  return null;
}
}

private void loadConsumerKeys() {
try {
  Properties props = new Properties();
  InputStream stream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.oauth);
  props.load(stream);
  consumerKey = (String)props.get("consumer_key");
  consumerSecretKey = (String)props.get("consumer_secret_key");
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load consumer keys from oauth.properties", e);
}
}
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.testapp2.second"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
    android:name=".OTweetApplication" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".activities.Testapp2Activity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.AuthorizationActivity"      android:label="@string/authorization" />
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: For your issue I would just look at the "error" section in the LogCat and post the results here and we can point you in the right direction

Comment: here are the first 2 errors that the logcat is showing me: 11-23 10:16:34.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.testapp2.second/com.testapp2.second.activities.AuthorizationActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException                                      and: 11-23 10:16:34.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2443)

Comment: please add the code/exception to your post, not as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first exception says everything: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

You should never ever do network stuff on the UI thread. You should do it in a Thread/AsyncTask.

If you provide us some code of your activity, we can say you what you should change.

Update:

In your `onResume()` of `AuthorizationActivity` you call `app.beginAuthorization();` which can call `twitter.getOAuthRequestToken()` which, as far as I saw in the twitter4j api, makes network connections. So this shouldn't be done in `onResume()` which runs in the UI Thread/Main Thread.

My advice: Make the twitter communication/authentication in an `AsyncTask` as you never know how fast/slow a connection might be. You should test your current application while having a slow connection. I guess you might get slow response of your application and/or an `application not responding` message.

Read this for further information: [Designing for Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)

The reason it worked below 4.0 was: it was introduced in API 11: [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Comment: I have about 4 activities/classes plus the manifest, will post above.

Comment: @EdmundRojas please post the code for `AuthorizationActivity` first. Than you should get the idea...

Comment: sorry for the delay, I finally was able to post the activities, apologies for missing this msg about the authorization activity.

Comment: also alot of the network tasks I handle using async tasks in the later versions of the code this is just a basic authentication example t make sure everything is working, fow whatever strange reason this works in 2.1 and 2.2 but wont work in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Imo ddms, there you can see logcat that will tell you all you need to know about what is happening to your app. I'm not sure about r15, mainly because i have being using a device to debug, but on older versions the emulator couldn't get all exceptions, making the debug phase painful

Answer (score 0):

DDMS is not a source code debugger, it provides:

- port-forwarding services
- screen capture on the device
- thread and heap information on the device
- logcat, process, and radio state information
- incoming call and SMS spoofing
- location data spoofing

On the other hand, with Eclipse you can set breakpoints in your code.